# Multiplication and Data Validation between two lists

Tags: python, list

I would like to validate data and perform some math using two lists. First I would like to ensure that the first element each list matches then I would like to mulitply the second, third and fourth items of the second list by the second item of the first list. I would like to create a new list, then sum the elements of that list.

The lists look something like this:

```
lista = [(1, 500), (2, 600), (3, 333)]

listb = [(1, 10, 11, 10.5), (2, 99, 100, 100), (3, 50, 51, 50)]
```

Before listc is created, I would like to ensure the first elements of each sub-list match between the lists. Then I would like to get a list that multiples the elements that looks like:

```
listc = [(1, 5000, 5500, 5250), (2, 59400, 60000, 60000), (3, 16650, 16983, 16650)]
```

Then I would like to create a fourth list where the elements are summed, like so:

```
listd = [(6 (doesn't necessarily have to sum this element), 81050, 81650, 81900)]
```

I have been looking into the "zip" function. I know that the function could do the multiplication, but how can it do the validation?

Comment: `zip` does not do multiplication. `zip` is in fact not much more than a *transpose*.

Comment: Have you considered switching over to numpy?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Is the code to create a numpy array similar to regular lists. RIght now I am appending data to an empty list.

I will look into making numpy arrays.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this in Python3:

```
from functools import reduce
lista = [(1, 500), (2, 600), (3, 333)]
listb = [(1, 10, 11, 10.5), (2, 99, 100, 100), (3, 50, 51, 50)]
if not all(c == d for (c, e), (d, *h) in zip(lista, listb)) or len(lista) != len(listb) or any(any(b is None for b in i) for i in lista) or any(any(b is None for b in i) for i in listb):
   raise ValueError("lists not validated")
new_listing = [(c, *[d*i for i in e]) for (c, d), (h, *e) in zip(lista, listb) if c == h]
final_listing = [reduce(lambda x, y:(x[0]+y[0], *[a+b for a, b in zip(x[1:], y[1:])]), new_listing)]
print(new_listing)
print(final_listing)
```

Output:

```
[(1, 5000, 5500, 5250.0), (2, 59400, 60000, 60000), (3, 16650, 16983, 16650)]
[(6, 81050, 82483, 81900.0)]
```

**Edit:**

Solution that sorts initial input:

```
from functools import reduce
lista = [(1, 500), (2, 600), (3, 333)]
listb = [(1, 10, 11, 10.5), (2, 99, 100, 100), (3, 50, 51, 50)]
lista = sorted(lista, key=lambda x:x[0])
listb = sorted(listb, key=lambda x:x[0])
new_listing = [(c, *[d*i for i in e]) for (c, d), (h, *e) in zip(lista, listb) if c == h]
final_listing = [reduce(lambda x, y:(x[0]+y[0], *[a+b for a, b in zip(x[1:], y[1:])]), new_listing)]
```

Edit 2:

Python 2.7 solution:

```
lista = [(1, 500), (2, 600), (3, 333)]
listb = [(1, 10, 11, 10.5), (2, 99, 100, 100), (3, 50, 51, 50)]
if not all(c == d[0] for (c, e), d in zip(lista, listb)) or len(lista) != len(listb) or any(any(b is None for b in i) for i in lista) or any(any(b is None for b in i) for i in listb):
   raise ValueError("lists not validated")

new_listing = [tuple([c]+[d*i for i in h[1:]]) for (c, d), h in zip(lista, listb) if c == h[0]]
final_listing = [reduce(lambda x, y:tuple([x[0]+y[0]]+[a+b for a, b in zip(x[1:], y[1:])]), new_listing)]
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this looks really bad. What is it even doing? Why is there so much spaghetti in this code?

Comment: Gosh. What if `lista` and `listb` aren't sorted by the first element? What if one of the lists is shorter than the other?

Comment: @vaultah this answer assumes that the OP will be using the sorted input as posted; however, I will post a solution that takes your question into consideration.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I added additional unpacking to make this answer less convoluted.

Comment: My data should be sorted and both lists should contain the same number of sub-lists. However, I would like to break the code or something if the data does not validate. 

I also want to throw an error if any of the elements are equal to 'NULL'.

Comment: @MichaelCrowne can you clarify on the condition that has to be met to invalidate the data?

Comment: The first element of each sub-list is an ID. I would only like to multiply the two lists together if the IDs match.


I probably don't want to sort them because lista and listb are all created from a list that contains the IDs and should be sorted based on that ID list.

Comment: @MichaelCrowne please see my recent edit. I added a condition to check for the various invalidators that you mentioned.

Comment: @Ajax1234 I am using Python 2.7 and getting this error:

new_listing  = [(c, * [d*i for i in e]) for (c, d), (h, *e) in zip(lista, listb) if c == h]
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

What does the c, d, i, e, and h do?

Comment: @MichaelCrowne c, d, i, e, and h are used in unpacking the elements from the lists. `* ` is for list unpacking and is only supported in Python3. However, I will post a solution for Python2.

Comment: @MichaelCrowne please see my recent edit. I added a solution for Python 2.

Comment: @Ajax1234 Thanks so much. I have one more operation to perform but I am going to try to figure that out myself. I think I will use code very similar to what you told me.

Comment: @MichaelCrowne glad to help! If this answer assisted you, please consider accepting it.